# Promise reject not working inside of callback in jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I am trying to improve the test coverage of an existing project, tried to explore the mocking cabability of jest (to be honest I am very new to NodeJS, coming from a Java background) and thought that I have the basic understanding of it.  However, I run into a problem where I still could not work out why jest is behaving this way.

Sample implementation that I am writing test against (handler.js):

```
'use strict';

const profileStore = require('./store/profile-store');

module.exports.invoke = (event, context, callback) => {

  let id = context.id;

  // profileStore.read returns a Promise
  profileStore.read(id)
  .then((profile) => onSuccess(profile))
  .catch((err) => onErrorProfile(err));

  function onSuccess(profile) {
    callback(null, 'Found Profile: ' + profile.name);
  };

  function onErrorProfile(err) {
    callback(null, 'Error finding Profile');
  };

};
```

the test file (handler.test.js)

```
const handlerImp = require('./handler');

let event = {};

const profileStore = require('./stores/profile-store');
jest.mock('./stores/profile-store');


test('1 - should expect error with missing profile', () => {

  profileStore.read.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.reject('for some unexpected reason'));

  function callback(err, resp) {
      expect(resp).toEqual('Error finding Profile');
  }

  return handlerImp.invoke(event, null, callback)
});

test('2 - should expect result when profile is found', () => {

  profileStore.read.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve({name: 'Random Profile Name'}));

  function callback(err, resp) {
      expect(resp).toEqual('Found Profile: Random Profile Name');
  }

  return handlerImp.invoke(event, null, callback)
});

test('3 - should fail test when error messages mis-matched', () => {

  profileStore.read.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.reject('for some unexpected reason'));

  function callback(err, resp) {
      expect(resp).toEqual('Unable to find Profile');
  }

  return handlerImp.invoke(event, null, callback)
});
```

From test #1 and #2 I am pretty sure the tests confirm the happy path and exception case correct.

However, with test #3, even if jest detected the mis-matched expectation, the test is still being treated as a PASS, also very puzzling was the UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning, some posts on this site pointed out potential bugs in code, but I am pretty sure my other test case confirmed that Promise.reject is being caught and being handled in onErrorProfile().

> (node:87160) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): Error: expect(received).toEqual(expected)
>
> Expected value to equal:
>
> "Unable to find Profile"
>
> Received:
>
> "Error finding Profile"
>
> PASS  handler.test.js
>
> ✓ should expect error with missing profile (6ms)
>
> ✓ should expect result when profile is found (1ms)
>
> ✓ should fail test when error message matched (3ms)
>
> Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
>     Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
>     Snapshots:   0 total
>     Time:        0.791s, estimated 1s

Hope someone can point out what I have missed. Thanks in advance for your help.